# How to edit a single line on a file? on Java

Tags: java, html, css

I've made a Java program that allows the user to create a `.html` file for a website. The program asks the user for the content and that goes to an `array` and then when its finished to a `.html` file.

I was wondering if I can allow the user to edit a `css` file that's already created.

**For example,** Giving them the option of changing the body background color. I would have to find the line in the `css` file where that's located and then change it. Anyone know how can I do that?

P.S.: This is my first time posting, please be kind.

Comment: you have to load the file in memory, change it and write it back. You may do that in "chunks" but there is no way around it.

Comment: A library to parse and edit the file may be a good option. Have a look at [jstyleparser](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/jstyleparser/) or other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Three ways to do it (and possibly more):

1- Use a css parser to load your css file into an objects tree (Ex: http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/), access the value you want to change, change it and then write back the tree to a file

2- Use a css template containing some dedicated markup like @body_background_color@. Then search and replace all the markup by their corresponding values then write the result to a file

3- Use a java.io.RandomAccessFile : It allows to directly edit a file at specified positions. If you know at which byte the "body background color" start and end. Then you can replace the value by another

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm you could use. You'll need to convert it to code yourself:

1. Create an empty temporary file
2. Loop through all the lines in the
   input file
3. Perform any modifications to the line
4. Write the line to the temp file
5. Once done with all the lines, delete the input file
6. Move the temporary file to the previous location of the input file

Comment: Thanks a lot, that could work. But I was looking for a way to not having to loop through the entire file, mostly if it's a large file.

Comment: @Leo If your CSS file is over a megabyte, you're doing it wrong. Don't agonize over performance until you've proven it's a problem. You sound like you're staring like a deer in the headlights frightened to even try anything. Just write some code and you can improve it later. You can't improve nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a template engine like velocity to generate both the html and the css. The css template would look like:

```
...
body {
    ...
    background-color: ${bgcolor};
    ...
}
...
```

You would specify a value for the variable `bgcolor` and then generate the css file with the template engine.